# What is the mathematical term and symbol for division without remainders?

Tags: terminology

What is the mathematical term and symbol for division without remainders?

Take for example `322 / 100`.

I know `322 / 100` is division and the result is 3.22.
I know `322 % 100` is a modulo and the result is 22.

But what is the proper term and symbol for division with no remainder?

Eg, `322 SYMBOL 100` would give `3`.

Comment: You could do $\lfloor 322/100\rfloor$

Comment: One way would be to use the div operator: 322 div 100 = 3.

Comment: A commonly used term is "integer division" (or in some contexts, just "division", but that is rarer).

Comment: BTW, `%` is not commonly used in mathematics as an operator to denote modulus division. In programming, it is used in many languages which have inherited (or borrowed) it from C, but there are many exceptions (not just in languages older than C). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#In_programming_languages

Comment: Thanks @preferred_anon. Knowing the term 'integer division' was critical to being able to search for the topic in my programming language (and know what the preferred way to do integer division in that language is).

Comment: FWIW, in Python, there's a floor division operator, `//`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations & https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term is 'integer division'. The symbol used is $\lfloor \frac{322}{100} \rfloor$ or sometimes $[\frac{322}{100}]$ and $100\,|\,300$ if one is a divisor of the other.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using $100\mid 300$, because as far as I know it's way more common to find it referred to the *statement* that there is an integer $k$ such that $300=100k$, rather than to the *number* $3$ itself.

Comment: That's why I wrote "if one is a divisor of the other"!

Comment: It can't hurt to specify the nuance of what's a function and what's a statement.

Comment: $100\,|\,300$ is a symbol for a division without remainder - as asked. This is an academic discussion based on a question which can be read either way.

Comment: I added the term to this answer - hope that's OK.